# Grab next same value in Excel/Google Sheets for RANK/MATCH formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, rank

I have a list of players in Google Sheets that assigns them a rank based on wins, followed by some more match variables — standard stuff.

I then use the rank to order the players in a league table format.

However, when I have two more players with the same rank, I hit a problem. The easiest way to illustrate it is with a link to the spreadsheet. Left side is the data, right side is the outputted table:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n05ETFfF01uCwp1Q88Z0Zi8XkH-dNm29Ocb6yVP84rU/edit?usp=sharing

My aim is:

- To allow drawing players, and thus output:

  ```
  1= Player 1
  1= Player 2
  3  Player 3
  4  Player 4
  ```
- But *also* to add players with a rank of 0 (already calculated) to the bottom of the list, in no particular order, but below those who have played.

Comment: I think I wrote something about this here: [Multiple Ranked Returns from INDEX(…) with Duplicate Values](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2010-excel/multiple-ranked-returns-from-index-with-duplicate/0f258553-fd5f-47bb-99f1-ec72dc4e6135)

Answer (score 0):

May serve for ColumnM, but seems would require adjustments elsewhere:

```
=if(countif(I$2:I$8,I2)>1,IF((B2=0), 0, RANK(H2,$H$1:$H$531,0))&"=",IF((B2=0), 0, RANK(H2,$H$1:$H$531,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reproduce your table (excluding the ranking) with this in N1:

`=QUERY(A:G,"select * order by B desc, G desc",1)`

and then in M2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(N2:N),(COUNTIF(S2:S,">"&S2:S)+1)&IF(COUNTIF(S2:S,S2:S)>1,"=",),))`

Answer (score -1):

Any kind of algorithm is going to hate ties.  They will produce unpredictable results, logic errors.

So you might set up your ranking system to remove the ties.  Possibly use the date they joined the league for tiebreaker, which would allow you to rank the players with no stats as well.

Make the rules known to all players.  E.g. 3 points for a win, 1 point for a tie, 0 for a loss, tie goes to the player with highest total points scored.  If still tied, it goes to player in the league longer.  The likelihood of established players getting to the join-date tiebreaker should be as remote as you can make it, so your first tiebreaker should be one that produces a lot of diverse answers.

Also, I am not sure, but I think the reason your question got downvoted was because a) it's a bit vague, and b) in this day and age, you really don't want to be opening data files from unknown people.  A snapshot of data from your spreadsheet might have been a better illustration than a link to it.  I know I will not open your sheet...I don't know you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suppose they are some options. However, the date idea is no good, as the league has pretty much just started, and there are quite a few players to be added. So they will all have the same start date.

Also, the tie-ing is not on a per-game basis (it's table tennis, you can't tie), it's just due to scores and rank being exactly the same. Which, actually, is quite likely.

Thanks for the tips on the question. It's a shame it's even an issue really.

Comment: It also turns out I don't have enough reputation to post an image. Great.

Comment: Perhaps score the first round automatically and for later rounds use position in previous round as tiebreaker.

Or have a random drawing for seeds into the system and use seed number for first round tiebreaker, then use final ranking of each round to seed the next round.

Comment: As long as you are recommending that OP's post images, how about volunteering to transcribe the image into sample data so the rest of us who actually test solutions do not have to. @jpsear - A link to a worksheet without macros (an .XLSX *cannot* by nature contain a VBA project) is highly preferred (IMO) to an image where I will have to type up a bunch of sample data before testing a solution I offer up. If your question is macro-centric then post the relevant code in your question and leave it out of the workbook.

Comment: Ok, so I meant 'snapshot' not as an image file but as a block of sample data, such as a few lines in CSV format pasted into the question.  Fact remains I am not opening a google sheet from an untrusted source.  a) I do not know the security options in google sheets b) I can't access it from here due to network restrictions.  But that's my problem.